# Let container overlap on scroll, but only overlap a fixed height - Is this doable with only CSS?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible with only CSS to have the following effect:
I have two divs. One follows the other.
Now, if the user starts scrolling down the page (to see other content, more divs if you want..) the second div should "go up" (could also stay fixed and the first div goes down, I mean it would look the same) and overlap the first.
But only overlap for let's say 50px. After that, the behaviour is normal again, meaning that if you scroll further, those divs move out of the browser window eventually.

Have I made myself clear? I can add two coloured boxed to showcase if that helps.  I played around a bit and tried parallex/position fixed/sticky mixes, but none seem to work with a given height restriction. I just wonder if this is possible without javascript.

[image: Visual representation]

Comment: You should post code. A wall of text trying to explain what you want is less helpful then seeing what you are trying to do. In this case you could probably add an image or two that shows what you mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I used a combination of negative margin, z-index and position: sticky.

Added margin to the 2nd container to make it more visible.

```css
.sticky-wrapper {
  height: 310px;
  margin-bottom: -60px;
}

.content {
  z-index: -1;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  padding: 0 3%;
  height: 250px;
  background-color: green;
}

.foo {
  margin: 0 50px;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

.next-content {
  height: 1000px;
  background-color: khaki;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky-wrapper">
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
<div class="foo"></div>
<div class="next-content"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get this effect by using `position: sticky` on both elements. There are a few things that can stop this from taking place, like having `overflow: hidden` or not having a height set on the `parent` element.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="red-box">This is the red box</div>
  <div class="blue-box">this is the blue box</div>
</div>

<!-- needs space to be able to actually scroll on the page -->
<div class="container">
  <div class=""></div>
  <div class=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/* set the height of the container so that the sticky elements know how far they are meant to scroll  */
.container{
  min-height: 400px;
}

/* set your position sticky and a attribute that tells it when it should become sticky, in this case right at the top */
.red-box{
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
.blue-box{
  height: 400px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}
```

I have done a quick codepen example so that you can see this working. hope that helps.

https://codepen.io/Domnewmarch/pen/NWzqBde

Comment: This is a cool approach, but doesn't solve the issue of stopping the blue-box after overlapping 50px.